# Get Label names Selenium python

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriverwait

I want to be able to loop though region names. I opened a dropdown menu by doing the following:

```
Open_menu = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'baseSelector')))
Open_menu.click()
Dropdown_region = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'geolist_region')))
time.sleep(2)
```

In this menu i want to find all different elements so i can loop through them. I did this by doing.

```
Gemeentes = Dropdown_region.find_elements_by_xpath(".//label")
```

However, I want the "region" name so i can use this to put this in an input element.
One of the elements for which i want to find the region name looks like the following:

```
<li id="geoitem_358" data-id="358" data-level="gemeente" data-role="button">
<input class="geoitemradio" type="radio" name="geolist_regiongeoitem" id="rdgeoitem_358"><label for="rdgeoitem_358">Aalsmeer</label></li>
```

So i want a list of all regions, in case of the above i thus want "Aalsmeer"

How would i be able to get a list of all different region names ?
Or, if there is a better way to loop through each region instead of using the region names in an input element, please let me know.

link used : https://www.waarstaatjegemeente.nl/dashboard/bedrijvigheid-en-economie

Comment: Do you want to use a random region name from the list of available regions or get all the regions and iterate with each of them?

Comment: get all and iterate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the items from dropdown. Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and following css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.waarstaatjegemeente.nl/dashboard/bedrijvigheid-en-economie")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#baseSelector"))).click()
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul#geolist_region>li[data-level='gemeente']>label")))
alllist=[ele.text for ele in elements]
print(alllist)
print(len(alllist))
for item in alllist:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtgeoinput_region"))).clear()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtgeoinput_region"))).send_keys(item)
```

**Console output:**

```
['Aa en Hunze', 'Aalsmeer', 'Aalten', 'Achtkarspelen', 'Alblasserdam', 'Albrandswaard', 'Alkmaar', 'Almelo', 'Almere', 'Alphen aan den Rijn', 'Alphen-Chaam', 'Altena', 'Ameland', 'Amersfoort', 'Amstelveen', 'Amsterdam', 'Apeldoorn', 'Appingedam', 'Arnhem', 'Assen', 'Asten', 'Baarle-Nassau', 'Baarn', 'Barendrecht', 'Barneveld', 'Beek', 'Beekdaelen', 'Beemster', 'Beesel', 'Berg en Dal', 'Bergeijk', 'Bergen (L.)', 'Bergen (NH.)', 'Bergen op Zoom', 'Berkelland', 'Bernheze', 'Best', 'Beuningen', 'Beverwijk', 'Bladel', 'Blaricum', 'Bloemendaal', 'Bodegraven-Reeuwijk', 'Boekel', 'Borger-Odoorn', 'Borne', 'Borsele', 'Boxmeer', 'Boxtel', 'Breda', 'Brielle', 'Bronckhorst', 'Brummen', 'Brunssum', 'Bunnik', 'Bunschoten', 'Buren', 'Capelle aan den IJssel', 'Castricum', 'Coevorden', 'Cranendonck', 'Cuijk', 'Culemborg', 'Dalfsen', 'Dantumadiel', 'De Bilt', 'De Fryske Marren', 'De Ronde Venen', 'De Wolden', 'Delft', 'Delfzijl', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Deurne', 'Deventer', 'Diemen', 'Dinkelland', 'Doesburg', 'Doetinchem', 'Dongen', 'Dordrecht', 'Drechterland', 'Drimmelen', 'Dronten', 'Druten', 'Duiven', 'Echt-Susteren', 'Edam-Volendam', 'Ede', 'Eemnes', 'Eersel', 'Eijsden-Margraten', 'Eindhoven', 'Elburg', 'Emmen', 'Enkhuizen', 'Enschede', 'Epe', 'Ermelo', 'Etten-Leur', 'Geertruidenberg', 'Geldrop-Mierlo', 'Gemert-Bakel', 'Gennep', 'Gilze en Rijen', 'Goeree-Overflakkee', 'Goes', 'Goirle', 'Gooise Meren', 'Gorinchem', 'Gouda', 'Grave', 'Groningen', 'Gulpen-Wittem', 'Haaksbergen', 'Haaren', 'Haarlem', 'Haarlemmermeer', 'Halderberge', 'Hardenberg', 'Harderwijk', 'Hardinxveld-Giessendam', 'Harlingen', 'Hattem', 'Heemskerk', 'Heemstede', 'Heerde', 'Heerenveen', 'Heerhugowaard', 'Heerlen', 'Heeze-Leende', 'Heiloo', 'Hellendoorn', 'Hellevoetsluis', 'Helmond', 'Hendrik-Ido-Ambacht', 'Hengelo', 'Het Hogeland', 'Heumen', 'Heusden', 'Hillegom', 'Hilvarenbeek', 'Hilversum', 'Hoeksche Waard', 'Hof van Twente', 'Hollands Kroon', 'Hoogeveen', 'Hoorn', 'Horst aan de Maas', 'Houten', 'Huizen', 'Hulst', 'IJsselstein', 'Kaag en Braassem', 'Kampen', 'Kapelle', 'Katwijk', 'Kerkrade', 'Koggenland', 'Krimpen aan den IJssel', 'Krimpenerwaard', 'Laarbeek', 'Landerd', 'Landgraaf', 'Landsmeer', 'Langedijk', 'Lansingerland', 'Laren', 'Leeuwarden', 'Leiden', 'Leiderdorp', 'Leidschendam-Voorburg', 'Lelystad', 'Leudal', 'Leusden', 'Lingewaard', 'Lisse', 'Lochem', 'Loon op Zand', 'Lopik', 'Loppersum', 'Losser', 'Maasdriel', 'Maasgouw', 'Maassluis', 'Maastricht', 'Medemblik', 'Meerssen', 'Meierijstad', 'Meppel', 'Middelburg', 'Midden-Delfland', 'Midden-Drenthe', 'Midden-Groningen', 'Mill en Sint Hubert', 'Moerdijk', 'Molenlanden', 'Montferland', 'Montfoort', 'Mook en Middelaar', 'Neder-Betuwe', 'Nederweert', 'Nieuwegein', 'Nieuwkoop', 'Nijkerk', 'Nijmegen', 'Nissewaard', 'Noardeast-Fryslân', 'Noord-Beveland', 'Noordenveld', 'Noordoostpolder', 'Noordwijk', 'Nuenen c.a.', 'Nunspeet', 'Oegstgeest', 'Oirschot', 'Oisterwijk', 'Oldambt', 'Oldebroek', 'Oldenzaal', 'Olst-Wijhe', 'Ommen', 'Oost Gelre', 'Oosterhout', 'Ooststellingwerf', 'Oostzaan', 'Opmeer', 'Opsterland', 'Oss', 'Oude IJsselstreek', 'Ouder-Amstel', 'Oudewater', 'Overbetuwe', 'Papendrecht', 'Peel en Maas', 'Pekela', 'Pijnacker-Nootdorp', 'Purmerend', 'Putten', 'Raalte', 'Reimerswaal', 'Renkum', 'Renswoude', 'Reusel-De Mierden', 'Rheden', 'Rhenen', 'Ridderkerk', 'Rijssen-Holten', 'Rijswijk', 'Roerdalen', 'Roermond', 'Roosendaal', 'Rotterdam', 'Rozendaal', 'Rucphen', 'Schagen', 'Scherpenzeel', 'Schiedam', 'Schiermonnikoog', 'Schouwen-Duiveland', "'s-Hertogenbosch", 'Simpelveld', 'Sint Anthonis', 'Sint-Michielsgestel', 'Sittard-Geleen', 'Sliedrecht', 'Sluis', 'Smallingerland', 'Soest', 'Someren', 'Son en Breugel', 'Stadskanaal', 'Staphorst', 'Stede Broec', 'Steenbergen', 'Steenwijkerland', 'Stein', 'Stichtse Vecht', 'Súdwest-Fryslân', 'Terneuzen', 'Terschelling', 'Texel', 'Teylingen', 'Tholen', 'Tiel', 'Tilburg', 'Tubbergen', 'Twenterand', 'Tynaarlo', 'Tytsjerksteradiel', 'Uden', 'Uitgeest', 'Uithoorn', 'Urk', 'Utrecht', 'Utrechtse Heuvelrug', 'Vaals', 'Valkenburg aan de Geul', 'Valkenswaard', 'Veendam', 'Veenendaal', 'Veere', 'Veldhoven', 'Velsen', 'Venlo', 'Venray', 'Vijfheerenlanden', 'Vlaardingen', 'Vlieland', 'Vlissingen', 'Voerendaal', 'Voorschoten', 'Voorst', 'Vught', 'Waadhoeke', 'Waalre', 'Waalwijk', 'Waddinxveen', 'Wageningen', 'Wassenaar', 'Waterland', 'Weert', 'Weesp', 'West Betuwe', 'West Maas en Waal', 'Westerkwartier', 'Westerveld', 'Westervoort', 'Westerwolde', 'Westland', 'Weststellingwerf', 'Westvoorne', 'Wierden', 'Wijchen', 'Wijdemeren', 'Wijk bij Duurstede', 'Winterswijk', 'Woensdrecht', 'Woerden', 'Wormerland', 'Woudenberg', 'Zaanstad', 'Zaltbommel', 'Zandvoort', 'Zeewolde', 'Zeist', 'Zevenaar', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zoeterwoude', 'Zuidplas', 'Zundert', 'Zutphen', 'Zwartewaterland', 'Zwijndrecht', 'Zwolle', 'Gemeente onbekend']
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text e.g. *Aalsmeer*, from each `<label>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#geolist_region li[data-level='gemeente'] label")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='geolist_region']//li[@data-level='gemeente']//label")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Aa en Hunze', 'Aalsmeer', 'Aalten', 'Achtkarspelen', 'Alblasserdam', 'Albrandswaard', 'Alkmaar', 'Almelo', 'Almere', 'Alphen aan den Rijn', 'Alphen-Chaam', 'Altena', 'Ameland', 'Amersfoort', 'Amstelveen', 'Amsterdam', 'Apeldoorn', 'Appingedam', 'Arnhem', 'Assen', 'Asten', 'Baarle-Nassau', 'Baarn', 'Barendrecht', 'Barneveld', 'Beek', 'Beekdaelen', 'Beemster', 'Beesel', 'Berg en Dal', 'Bergeijk', 'Bergen (L.)', 'Bergen (NH.)', 'Bergen op Zoom', 'Berkelland', 'Bernheze', 'Best', 'Beuningen', 'Beverwijk', 'Bladel', 'Blaricum', 'Bloemendaal', 'Bodegraven-Reeuwijk', 'Boekel', 'Borger-Odoorn', 'Borne', 'Borsele', 'Boxmeer', 'Boxtel', 'Breda', 'Brielle', 'Bronckhorst', 'Brummen', 'Brunssum', 'Bunnik', 'Bunschoten', 'Buren', 'Capelle aan den IJssel', 'Castricum', 'Coevorden', 'Cranendonck', 'Cuijk', 'Culemborg', 'Dalfsen', 'Dantumadiel', 'De Bilt', 'De Fryske Marren', 'De Ronde Venen', 'De Wolden', 'Delft', 'Delfzijl', 'Den Haag', 'Den Helder', 'Deurne', 'Deventer', 'Diemen', 'Dinkelland', 'Doesburg', 'Doetinchem', 'Dongen', 'Dordrecht', 'Drechterland', 'Drimmelen', 'Dronten', 'Druten', 'Duiven', 'Echt-Susteren', 'Edam-Volendam', 'Ede', 'Eemnes', 'Eersel', 'Eijsden-Margraten', 'Eindhoven', 'Elburg', 'Emmen', 'Enkhuizen', 'Enschede', 'Epe', 'Ermelo', 'Etten-Leur', 'Geertruidenberg', 'Geldrop-Mierlo', 'Gemert-Bakel', 'Gennep', 'Gilze en Rijen', 'Goeree-Overflakkee', 'Goes', 'Goirle', 'Gooise Meren', 'Gorinchem', 'Gouda', 'Grave', 'Groningen', 'Gulpen-Wittem', 'Haaksbergen', 'Haaren', 'Haarlem', 'Haarlemmermeer', 'Halderberge', 'Hardenberg', 'Harderwijk', 'Hardinxveld-Giessendam', 'Harlingen', 'Hattem', 'Heemskerk', 'Heemstede', 'Heerde', 'Heerenveen', 'Heerhugowaard', 'Heerlen', 'Heeze-Leende', 'Heiloo', 'Hellendoorn', 'Hellevoetsluis', 'Helmond', 'Hendrik-Ido-Ambacht', 'Hengelo', 'Het Hogeland', 'Heumen', 'Heusden', 'Hillegom', 'Hilvarenbeek', 'Hilversum', 'Hoeksche Waard', 'Hof van Twente', 'Hollands Kroon', 'Hoogeveen', 'Hoorn', 'Horst aan de Maas', 'Houten', 'Huizen', 'Hulst', 'IJsselstein', 'Kaag en Braassem', 'Kampen', 'Kapelle', 'Katwijk', 'Kerkrade', 'Koggenland', 'Krimpen aan den IJssel', 'Krimpenerwaard', 'Laarbeek', 'Landerd', 'Landgraaf', 'Landsmeer', 'Langedijk', 'Lansingerland', 'Laren', 'Leeuwarden', 'Leiden', 'Leiderdorp', 'Leidschendam-Voorburg', 'Lelystad', 'Leudal', 'Leusden', 'Lingewaard', 'Lisse', 'Lochem', 'Loon op Zand', 'Lopik', 'Loppersum', 'Losser', 'Maasdriel', 'Maasgouw', 'Maassluis', 'Maastricht', 'Medemblik', 'Meerssen', 'Meierijstad', 'Meppel', 'Middelburg', 'Midden-Delfland', 'Midden-Drenthe', 'Midden-Groningen', 'Mill en Sint Hubert', 'Moerdijk', 'Molenlanden', 'Montferland', 'Montfoort', 'Mook en Middelaar', 'Neder-Betuwe', 'Nederweert', 'Nieuwegein', 'Nieuwkoop', 'Nijkerk', 'Nijmegen', 'Nissewaard', 'Noardeast-Fryslân', 'Noord-Beveland', 'Noordenveld', 'Noordoostpolder', 'Noordwijk', 'Nuenen c.a.', 'Nunspeet', 'Oegstgeest', 'Oirschot', 'Oisterwijk', 'Oldambt', 'Oldebroek', 'Oldenzaal', 'Olst-Wijhe', 'Ommen', 'Oost Gelre', 'Oosterhout', 'Ooststellingwerf', 'Oostzaan', 'Opmeer', 'Opsterland', 'Oss', 'Oude IJsselstreek', 'Ouder-Amstel', 'Oudewater', 'Overbetuwe', 'Papendrecht', 'Peel en Maas', 'Pekela', 'Pijnacker-Nootdorp', 'Purmerend', 'Putten', 'Raalte', 'Reimerswaal', 'Renkum', 'Renswoude', 'Reusel-De Mierden', 'Rheden', 'Rhenen', 'Ridderkerk', 'Rijssen-Holten', 'Rijswijk', 'Roerdalen', 'Roermond', 'Roosendaal', 'Rotterdam', 'Rozendaal', 'Rucphen', 'Schagen', 'Scherpenzeel', 'Schiedam', 'Schiermonnikoog', 'Schouwen-Duiveland', "'s-Hertogenbosch", 'Simpelveld', 'Sint Anthonis', 'Sint-Michielsgestel', 'Sittard-Geleen', 'Sliedrecht', 'Sluis', 'Smallingerland', 'Soest', 'Someren', 'Son en Breugel', 'Stadskanaal', 'Staphorst', 'Stede Broec', 'Steenbergen', 'Steenwijkerland', 'Stein', 'Stichtse Vecht', 'Súdwest-Fryslân', 'Terneuzen', 'Terschelling', 'Texel', 'Teylingen', 'Tholen', 'Tiel', 'Tilburg', 'Tubbergen', 'Twenterand', 'Tynaarlo', 'Tytsjerksteradiel', 'Uden', 'Uitgeest', 'Uithoorn', 'Urk', 'Utrecht', 'Utrechtse Heuvelrug', 'Vaals', 'Valkenburg aan de Geul', 'Valkenswaard', 'Veendam', 'Veenendaal', 'Veere', 'Veldhoven', 'Velsen', 'Venlo', 'Venray', 'Vijfheerenlanden', 'Vlaardingen', 'Vlieland', 'Vlissingen', 'Voerendaal', 'Voorschoten', 'Voorst', 'Vught', 'Waadhoeke', 'Waalre', 'Waalwijk', 'Waddinxveen', 'Wageningen', 'Wassenaar', 'Waterland', 'Weert', 'Weesp', 'West Betuwe', 'West Maas en Waal', 'Westerkwartier', 'Westerveld', 'Westervoort', 'Westerwolde', 'Westland', 'Weststellingwerf', 'Westvoorne', 'Wierden', 'Wijchen', 'Wijdemeren', 'Wijk bij Duurstede', 'Winterswijk', 'Woensdrecht', 'Woerden', 'Wormerland', 'Woudenberg', 'Zaanstad', 'Zaltbommel', 'Zandvoort', 'Zeewolde', 'Zeist', 'Zevenaar', 'Zoetermeer', 'Zoeterwoude', 'Zuidplas', 'Zundert', 'Zutphen', 'Zwartewaterland', 'Zwijndrecht', 'Zwolle', 'Gemeente onbekend']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```